# Escape double quotes in string in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

How to do escape double quote in crystal report function
My Code:

```
Function GetResult()
        Dim Result As String
if () the
      Result = "ckl"B"
else 
end if
```

Note: I am using basic syntax for function

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to write a function ..Simply way is

`replace({table.field},"""","" )`  or

`replace({table.field},chrW(34),"" )`

Comment: I have wrote above function in that Result string contain double quotes for that i want to escape " see this  Result = "ckl"B"  here value is ckl"B