# how to move special char in a string from beginning to the end in crystal reports

Tags: string, crystal-reports, special-characters

in my program I (after many procedures) get tokenized words. Unfortunately due to reversing them they hold punctuation characters at the beginning of a word eg. **"BARGE "UR 106**
How to move that " from the beginning to the end -> **BARGE "UR 106"**
another example: **(.REIS (HASAN M** should be -> **REIS (HASAN M.)**

Up to now I've tried:

```
    {DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA} startswith ["\"","\(","\."\,"\(\."]
    then 
    Local StringVar str:={DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA}[0]
    TrimLeft ({DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA})
    {DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA}&str;
```

But that gives me errors:
A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here.

How to fix that? or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your formula.

1. `startswith` expects a string not an array of strings.
2. Only the double qoute must be escaped, but you did it wrong. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611299/escape-double-quotes-in-string-in-crystal-report))

While a solution with `startswith` is also possible, I have used the `Left`-function instead. In your third example one have to check two characters, so this must be checked first and output another result.

```
if Left({DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA}, 2) = "(." Then
    Mid({DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA}, 3) + ".)"
else if Left({DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA}, 1) in ["""", "(", ".", ","] Then
    Mid({DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA}, 2) + Left({DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA}, 1)
else
    {DOCHS14.SHEM__ONIA}
```